# Why pthread_join on itself doesn't result in error or deadlock?

Tags: c, multithreading

https://repl.it/repls/ColdSilentTriangles

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
pthread_t th;

void *fp(void *args) {
  printf("Thread running...");
  pthread_join(th, NULL);
  printf("Thread waiting...");
  return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("Hello World\n");
  pthread_create(&th, NULL, fp, NULL);
  pthread_join(th, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

From `man pthread_join`,

> The pthread_join() function suspends execution of the calling thread until the target thread ter-minates unless the target thread has already terminated.

Why the program doesn't result in deadlock?
Why there is no error generated? 
Why "Thread waiting..." is outputed onto the screen when the pthread_join() is supposed to block the thread?

Comment: How do you know? One of the possible return values of `pthread_join()` is `EDEADLK`, but you don't even check.

Comment: Yeah, it's really weird that you say no error is generated when you didn't even check.

Answer (score 3):

`pthread_join` doesn't block execution and instead returns `EDEADLK` in your example.